# Is it possible to load file from memory?

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

Is it possible to load a `.blend` file from memory? Thus, open it without using its filepath (`bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=l)`) but its `data`.

Theoretical example:

```
import bpy

filepath = r"C:\Users\Blender\script.blend"

with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
    r = f.read()

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(r)
```

If it would be possible to do it using `command line`, that'd be great too.

Comment: Not AFAIK. What's your goal with this? Why would it be so bad to save the file to disk first?